# Querying Servers with UDP using?

Tags: java, multithreading, udp, netty, apache-mina

I want to query servers (about 100 can increase)

i am currently querying them iteratively  in a loop one by one but it takes too much time.

I have found 2-3 options on net like **MultiThreading**  , **Netty** etc.

Which one should i choose ?

here is the algo ->

Send 100 UDP packets to 100 servers at **ONCE**

100 servers respond with 1 UDP packet each .( No more communication is required)

i need to process that 1 UDP packet and store it somewhere. (My server should accept multiple packets at same time)

Edit:  **Game** Servers

Comment: How do you want to handle UDP packets which get lost?

Comment: If no reply is received then either packets are lost or server is offline . Timeout will serve the purpose for offline server.. lost packets are not a problem because i will be sending these 100 packets at a short interval of time.

Comment: In which case, you can just use DataGrams. You can also send packets a few times like retries if you don't get a response.

Comment: What is it you need to know?  Would a ping suffice?

Comment: should i use datagrams using multithreading ?  will it work if server list gets huge ... I am using datagram packets currently but in a loop..

Comment: @Thor server will reply with info which will be stored in DB

Comment: Considered making it the responsibility of each server to report back regularily?

Comment: servers are game servers which send reply if queried.

Comment: each server has different ip / port eg. 100.101.102.103:27035  ,
200.201.202.203:27010  . i dont think multicast would be possible.